# Finding all possible values with if in Scheme

Tags: if-statement, scheme

i try to do homework but i'm in the trouble with it.. there are some facts about busses and voyagers:

I try to write code that give alternative ways (that can be direct way or maximum one transfer) to destination of voyager. For example:

```
>(findways 'john)
(list (list 'b002))
>(findways 'merry)
(list (list 'b005) (list 'b001 'b002))
>(findways 'lerry)
(list (list 'b006) (list 'b004 'b003) (list 'b007 'b008))
```

So.. first find the way to no need to transfer, after that find the way or ways to need only one transfer...

after these i need to find also shortest way with another function:

```
>(findshort 'jhon)
(list 'b002)  ; this is because the only way is
>(findshort 'merry) 
(list 'b005)  ; this because b005 travel time is 8, b001+b002 is 15
>(findshort 'lerry)
(list 'b004 'b003) ; this is because b006 is 18, b007+b008 is 16 but b004+b003 is 13
```

Thanks a lot

p.s.: i'm not allowed to use *!* and *let*

Comment: This homework isn't appropriate for a beginning student. In particular, it's hard to test, because "busses" isn't an input to the function. If it were, I would ask you to write simple test cases; in particular, the test case that arises when the list of busses is empty, the test cases that arises when the list of busses is of length 1, etc.  Bad instructor.  Or maybe this class assumes that you're already a skilled functional programmer, in which case the problem is yours :(.

Comment: :( it just a homework but i really don't understand wheter teacher try to teach this language or try to satisfy his ego on us.. i'm not a skilled func. prog. just a student

Comment: Here's my best suggestion: read How To Design Programs (www.htdp.org); it will teach you how to do *all* of this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution but it should help you get started.
Try breaking the problem up into smaller, easier functions, like so:

```
;; (define buses ...)
;; (define voyagers ....)

(define findways
   (lambda (voyager)
     (find_bus_routes (lookup_voyager_route voyager voyagers) buses)))

(define lookup_voyager_route
  (lambda (voyager voyager_lst)
    (if (null? voyager_lst)
        '()
        (if (equal? voyager (caar voyager_lst))
            (cdar voyager_lst)
            (lookup_voyager_route voyager (cdr voyager_lst))))))

(define find_bus_routes
  (lambda (sd_lst bus_routes)
    (if (or (null? sd_lst) (null? bus_routes))
        '()
        (if (equal? (car sd_lst) (cadar bus_routes))
            ;; perfect match
            (if (equal? (cadr sd_lst) (caddar bus_routes)) 
                (cons (caar bus_routes) ;; keep bus number
                      (find_bus_routes sd_lst (cdr bus_routes)))
                ;; partial match could be improved
                (cons (list (caar bus_routes) 
                            (match_route (caddar bus_routes)
                                         (cadr sd_lst) buses))
                      (find_bus_routes sd_lst (cdr bus_routes))))
            (find_bus_routes sd_lst (cdr bus_routes))))))

(define match_route
   (lambda (start dest routes)
     (if (null? routes)
         routes
         (if (and (equal? start (cadar routes))
                  (equal? dest (caddar routes)))
             (caar routes)
             (match_route start dest (cdr routes))))))
```

Once you have a list of the possible routes, it's easy to figure out the shortest distance.

Comment: i try to understand this code but i'm confused.. it didn't give the correct rotation just find the start cities and even it reach the 3 option programm gives error. :(

Comment: I had a bit of trouble formatting it here, could you provide the error you received?  This code is not complete, it should only give all the alternatives.

Comment: caddr: expects argument of type <caddrable value>; given (list (list 'b007 'malibu 'atalanta 5) (list 'b008 'atalanta 'ookala 11))      i write it in advanced student so you write "caddar" but i change it "caddr"

Comment: If you're using racket choose "determine language from source" and use #lang racket

Comment: i m using dr.scheme but there is one more homework restriction my code must be in advanced student language :(

Comment: Ok, I think the only problem is caddar, so I suggest trying to figure out what (caddar bus_routes) and (caddar routes) actually does and make a separate, simpler function for it.